# Convert hex color string to RGB color

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to convert hex color to RGB color.

I used the following code:

```
Me.BackColor = RGB("#000000")
```

But then it throws the following exception:

```
Argument not specified for parameter 'Green' of 'Public Function RGB(Red As Integer, Green As Integer, Blue As Integer) As Integer'
```

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

By ColorTranslator:

```
ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#003399")
```

Other Ways:

```
Public Function ConvertToRbg(ByVal HexColor As String) As Color
    Dim Red As String
    Dim Green As String
    Dim Blue As String
    HexColor = Replace(HexColor, "#", "")
    Red = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 1, 2))
    Green = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 3, 2))
    Blue = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 5, 2))
    Return Color.FromArgb(Red, Green, Blue)
End Function
```

or:

```
Public Shared Function HexToColor(ByVal hexColor As String) As Color
    If hexColor.IndexOf("#"c) <> -1 Then
        hexColor = hexColor.Replace("#", "")
    End If
    Dim red As Integer = 0
    Dim green As Integer = 0
    Dim blue As Integer = 0
    If hexColor.Length = 6 Then
        red = Integer.Parse(hexColor.Substring(0, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
        green = Integer.Parse(hexColor.Substring(2, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
        blue = Integer.Parse(hexColor.Substring(4, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
    ElseIf hexColor.Length = 3 Then
        red = Integer.Parse(hexColor(0).ToString() + hexColor(0).ToString(), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
        green = Integer.Parse(hexColor(1).ToString() + hexColor(1).ToString(), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
        blue = Integer.Parse(hexColor(2).ToString() + hexColor(2).ToString(), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
    End If
    Return Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue)
End Function
```

or:

```
    Dim c As String = "#ffffff"
    c = Replace(c, "#", "")
    c = "&H" & c
    ColorTranslator.FromOle(c)
```

or:

```
Public Function hexToRbgNew(ByVal Hex As String) As Color
    Hex = Replace(Hex, "#", "")
    Dim red As String = "&H" & Hex.Substring(0, 2)
    Hex = Replace(Hex, red, "", , 1)
    Dim green As String = "&H" & Hex.Substring(0, 2)
    Hex = Replace(Hex, green, "", , 1)
    Dim blue As String = "&H" & Hex.Substring(0, 2)
    Hex = Replace(Hex, blue, "", , 1)
    Return Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me: (vb.Net)

```
cell.BackColor = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(&H3399FF)
```