# Convert VBColor value to HEX value in C#

Tags: c#, colors, hex

Is there any way to convert vbcolor value to hex value in C#? For example: &H004080 (vbcolor) to #804000 (hex value). Or should I convert the value externally and then put the converted value into my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I done and it worked so far:

```
public static string VBColorToHexConverter(string vbColor) 
{
  string hexValue;
  string r = "", g = "", b = "";

  char[] vbValue = vbColor.ToCharArray();

  for (int i = 0; i < vbValue.Length; i++) 
  {
    r = vbValue[6].ToString() + vbValue[7].ToString();
    g = vbValue[4].ToString() + vbValue[5].ToString();
    b = vbValue[2].ToString() + vbValue[3].ToString();
  }

  hexValue = "#" + r + g + b;

  return hexValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a conversion of hex color to string:

Vb code snippet from here [Convert hex color string to RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356486/convert-hex-color-string-to-rgb-color):

```
Public Function ConvertToRbg(ByVal HexColor As String) As Color
    Dim Red As String
    Dim Green As String
    Dim Blue As String
    HexColor = Replace(HexColor, "#", "")
    Red = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 1, 2))
    Green = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 3, 2))
    Blue = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 5, 2))
    Return Color.FromArgb(Red, Green, Blue)
End Function
```

C# - Or use this library described on this question:

[How to get Color from Hexadecimal color code using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net)

```
using System.Windows.Media;

Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991");
```

Comment: Hi @Thiago, I;ve tried with the ColorConverter in C#, but it doesn't work since my input value is on vb color format. I've to convert the vb color value to hex value first, then I put the converted value to the ColorConverter and it works. My problem now is the conversion from vb value to hex value.

Comment: YWah, I searched for that and I believe your answer is the best you can have on the conversion that you need.