# how to give a color?

Tags: vb.net, colors

I want to change border backcolors with this code.
rest of the code is working except first line : to set mycolor1 is not correct. given error any way what I have tried.

code :

```
Dim mycolor1 As Color = New Color RGB("#00FF00") ?   'here RGB is not recognized, marked with ~~~
Dim myBrush As Brush

'From Color to brush/pen
myBrush = New SolidColorBrush(mycolor1)

For Each Border In Me.Children
    Border.Background = myBrush
Next
```

How can I define a specific color by RGB or HEX here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert hex color string to RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356486/convert-hex-color-string-to-rgb-color)

Comment: `Using myBrush = New SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#00FF00"))  '  [...] Use te Brush [...] End Using`

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim mycolor1 As Color = Color.FromArgb(&H00FF00)
```

Comment: FromArgb(&H00FF00) has ~~~~~~~~~ and not recognized

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim mycolor1 As Color = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("&HFF0000")
```

this works fine in VS2022